# Why isn't my second 2 else if statement running?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why my second `else if` statement never runs. Can someone explain it to me?

```js
Name = window.prompt("Tell your First Name");

if (Name.endsWith('X') == true || Name.endsWith('x') == true) {
  meh = Name.slice(0, -1)
  console.log(meh)
} else if (Name.startsWith('X') == true || Name.startsWith('x') == true) {
  hello = Name.slice(1)
  console.log(hello)
} else if (Name.startsWith('X') == true || Name.startsWith('x') == true && Name.endsWith('X') == true || Name.endsWith('x') == true) {
  var result = Name.slice(1) && Name.slice(0, -1);
  console.log(result)
} else {
  console.log(Name)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask, including the specific input you're using and the specific result you are observing when you debug and how that differs from what you expect.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: You need to give us enough information to reproduce your problem .. including and most important here ... the name you are entering.   Without that, it is total guesswork because we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: 1. An expression `a || b && c || d` is evaluated like `a || (b && c) || d` 2. you need to go from the most specific case to the more generic cases, or the generic cases will be the active branch and all others will never run. (also: it's pretty obvious to me what the issue is and what's causing it, the code and the title are enough to figure this out)

Comment: Switch the order of your `else if` statements. (Put the second one before the first.)

Comment: It will never go into `} else if (Name.startsWith('X') == true || Name.startsWith('x') == true && Name.endsWith('X') == true || Name.endsWith('x') == true) {
` because the ones above it will match... Your check is also wrong

Comment: Here's a shorter and more readable way: https://jsfiddle.net/1fe2cutn/

Comment: It's conventional to name all variables lowerCamelCase, and classes UpperCamelCase, so `Name` would be called `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to start with most specific and go to the least. The code will not check all cases and figures out what is the best match, it starts from the top and first thing it matches it exits.

```js
const firstName = window.prompt("Tell your First Name");

const endsWith = firstName.toUpperCase().endsWith('X');
const startsWith = firstName.toUpperCase().startsWith('X');

if (startsWith && endsWith) { console.log('starts and ends'); }
else if (startsWith) {console.log('starts'); }
else if (endsWith) {console.log('ends'); }
else {console.log('nope'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your logic. For example:

- You have a compound conition to check of a character in string but, you should change the string case and then determine if the character you are looking for "startsWith" or "endWith" which appears to be the only to senarios your concerned with.
- secondly the "startsWith" and "endWith" functions natrually return a boolean value so equating the return with true or false would be redundant and uneccessary.
- If else
  execution of one or other
- If else if
  execute one or other - just enables the ability to take other senarios into consideration.

### for example:

```js
const Name = window.prompt("Tell your First Name");


if (Name.toUpperCase().endsWith('X')) {
  hello = Name.slice(1)
  console.log(hello)
} else if (Name.toUpperCase().startsWith('X')) {
  var result = Name.slice(1) && Name.slice(0, -1);
  console.log(result)
} else {
  console.log(Name)
}
```

### is the same above but it will execute twice because the block has been broken into two

```js
const Name = window.prompt("Tell your First Name");


if (Name.toUpperCase().endsWith('X')) {
  hello = Name.slice(1)
  console.log(hello)
}

if (Name.toUpperCase().startsWith('X')) {
  var result = Name.slice(1) && Name.slice(0, -1);
  console.log(result)
} else {
  console.log(Name)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You should move `startsWithX && endsWithX` to be first condition, otherwise one of above will take it's place
2. Convert your string to lowercase (or uppercase) and remove need for double check of `X` and `x`

```js
Name = window.prompt("Tell your First Name").toLowerCase();

console.log('Answer: ', Name);

if (Name.startsWith('x') == true && Name.endsWith('x') == true) {
  var result = Name.slice(1) && Name.slice(0, -1);
  console.log('Starts and ends with X', result)
} else if (Name.endsWith('x') == true) {
  meh = Name.slice(0, -1)
  console.log('Ends with X', meh)
} else if (Name.startsWith('x') == true) {
  hello = Name.slice(1)
  console.log('Starts with X', hello)
} else {
  console.log('Default', Name)
}
```